# Using MLP to associate integers (input) to histograms (outputs) using tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm struggling with solving this issue and I believe it is due to my data. I'm thinking about this as a few to many regression problem, but there could be a better approach in tensorflow.

**Training Data**

I have some data generated from a video sequence. For each frame of video I have a distribution of x,y positions for each cluster. There are 157,110 frames and 200,000 clusters. The frames and clusters are the inputs, which are integers and I think could be considered labels (I'll be using another network to learn the sequences of clusters later on). As each histogram is related to both a frame and clusterID, the input is not "one hot". The histograms (outputs) have 19+8 (x+y) bins where each count is rarely above 10, and could be normalized.

A subset of the training data is available [here](http://www.ekran.org/tmp/clusterProbability.csv): The first two columns are the frame and clusterID (inputs) and the remaining 19+8 columns are the histograms (outputs).

**What is the best network to learn to generate the appropriate histogram for a given frame/clusterID pair?**

The following code is my current attempt using an MLP. It does not converge; in fact cost does not decrease at all. Is there something wrong in my implementation, or my choice of MLP, or a lack of scaling in my input data?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# This program uses tensorflow to learn cluster probabilities and associate them with frame and cluster IDs

# Arguments
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("clusterProbabilityfile", help="CSV file containing cluster probabilities")
parser.add_argument("trainingIterations", type=int,  help="CSV file containing cluster probabilities")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Imports for ML
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

# Imports for loading CSV file
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile 
import csv

# Global vars
numInputUnits = 2;
numOutputUnits = 19+8
numHiddenUnits = (numOutputUnits-numInputUnits)/2
workingDirectory = args.clusterProbabilityfile.split('/')[0]+"/"
columnSplit = 2 # Column number that splits 

# Shuffle training set
def shuffleTrainingSet(trainingSet):
    trainingIndecies = np.arange(len(trainingSet.data)) # assumes len(data) == len(target)
    np.random.shuffle(trainingIndecies) # shuffle indecies
    data = trainingSet.data[trainingIndecies]
    target = trainingSet.target[trainingIndecies]
    training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.Dataset(data=data, target=target)
    return training_set

# Load training data from CSV file, convert to numpy arrays and construct Dataset
# Modified from tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header
# Should these be randomized???
with gfile.Open(args.clusterProbabilityfile) as csv_file:
    data_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
    data, target = [], []
    for row in data_file:
        target.append(row[columnSplit+1:]) # All elements past the split column.
        data.append(row[:columnSplit]) # All elements before and including the split column.

target = np.array(target, dtype=int)
data = np.array(data, dtype=int)
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.Dataset(data=data, target=target)
training_set = shuffleTrainingSet(training_set)

# Construct computation graph
# MLP approach (from https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py)
# Single hidden layer!
inputVec = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, numInputUnits]) 
outputVec = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, numOutputUnits])

# Weights
hiddenWeights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([numInputUnits, numHiddenUnits])) # inputUnits -> hiddenUnits
outputWeights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([numHiddenUnits, numOutputUnits])) # hiddenUnits -> outputUnits

# Biases
hiddenBiases = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([numHiddenUnits]))
outputBiases = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([numOutputUnits]))

# Contruct MLP from layers
hiddenLayer = tf.add(tf.matmul(inputVec, hiddenWeights), hiddenBiases) # input * weight + bias = hidden
hiddenLayer = tf.nn.relu(hiddenLayer) # RELU Activation function for hidden layer.
outputLayer = tf.add(tf.matmul(hiddenLayer, outputWeights), outputBiases) # hidden * weight + bias = output

# loss and optimizer
#cross_entropy = -(outputVec * tf.log(outputLayer) + (1 - outputVec) * tf.log(1 - outputLayer))
#cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(outputLayer, outputVec))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

# Compute graph
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for epoch in range(args.trainingIterations):
    training_set = shuffleTrainingSet(training_set) # Reshuffle for each epoch.
    epochCost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={inputVec: training_set.data, outputVec: training_set.target})
    print("{:d}\t{:f}".format(epoch, epochCost))

# Evaluate model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(outputLayer,1), tf.argmax(outputVec,1)) # compare output layer with target output vector.
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print("Cost:", sess.run(cost,feed_dict={inputVec: training_set.data, outputVec: training_set.target}))
print("Accuracy:", sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={inputVec: training_set.data, outputVec: training_set.target}))
```

Comment: Please provide input files to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Prune added a subset of the data to the question above.

Comment: Thanks.  I should be able to give this a test run in the next day or two.

Comment: I realized a problem with the way this problem is framed. In the sequence predictor the "frame id" will not have any meaning, and thus should not be an input to the MLP. Now I'm thinking I should solve both problems with a single network, which would be a RNN with a huge amount of dimensions where the distributions of each cluster for frame_t would be the input (200,000 clusters * 19+8 histograms) and output (frame_t+1). Unless there is a suggestion for another approach that does involve breaking the problem into two...